# How can I speed up Developer Console?

Tags: unit-test, debugging, developer-console

Since Salesforce have moved their test execution to be asynchronous in Spring '13 we are forced to use the Developer Console to see Code Coverage for a single test class.

My issue with this is that for me the Developer Console is really slow and often crashes my browser (using in Chrome and IE7 - pretty much unusable in IE but this is the version we use in the company).

Is there any way to speed this up so it's actually usable?

I know there's the idea of Workspaces, which I thought would let me remove some of the tabs at the top (Logs, Heap Dumps, Repository etc.) but I can't work out how to do that.

Answer (score 11):

To set up perspective you need to load some log first:

[image]

Then click on the "Perspective All" button and then navigate to "View Panels". Turn some off and save new perspective as "New one".

[image]

By the way you can use for example Force.com IDE too:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

The problem with the Developer Console is that it is written in JavaScript; this uses a lot of computing resources. Changing your perspective, reducing logging levels, etc, may help you, but in this case, your best bet is to do the following: upgrade your hardware and web browser.

If I had to spec it out, I'd make the following recommendations:

- Get at least the recommended amount of RAM for your OS (not the minimum); 4GB is great for Windows 7, and I'd recommend 8GB for Windows 8 (but 4GB is just fine).
- Get at least a dual core CPU running at least 2.0GHz per core. This gives 2.0GHz potentially dedicated to your browser. More cores won't help unless you also use the Force.com IDE/do other intensive tasks.
- Get at least Chrome 31, Firefox 26, or Internet Explorer 10. This is by far the most important factor. The newer browsers are more efficient by several magnitudes of speed. Also, salesforce.com is shortly discontinuing support for IE 7, so you may as well upgrade.

Note that this isn't an expensive upgrade. I bought my new Windows 8 dual core laptop with 4GB of RAM for about $250, and my new Windows 8 dual core desktop for $350. The Developer Console runs *beautifully* on these computers. Both machines sport a Windows Experience Index of about 4.9. My work computer has a 3.4 and still gets the job done in Internet Explorer and Chrome.

Just upgrading your browser will give you a measurably increased experience. If your company (usually IT) is resistant, tell them that IE 7 is losing global support (hint: IE 7 doesn't appear on the top 12 browsers at statcounter.com). Also, make sure you're on the latest and greatest Chrome, but keep in mind that Chrome is currently benchmarking slower than IE 10, by quite a bit.

Developers traditionally have needed more resources than the average computer user (except for, of course, gamers), and despite the cloud-based nature of force.com, the tools are still quite down to earth, which means you must have a decent amount of hardware and updated software.

*Edit*: [Supported Browsers](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=getstart_browser_overview.htm&language=en) specifically states:

> Internet Explorer 7 and 8 aren’t supported for the Developer Console

Comment: I have 16 GB of RAM and 4 cores (i7 @ 4GHz) and the developer console is still slow...

Comment: @Robs This answer was written by a much younger me. I've since learned that it really depends on *what* you're doing in the Developer Console. The biggest contributor to a slower Developer Console depends on how many streaming events you get. For example, if you're running a batch class that's generating 100 logs per second, you'll probably find the console may lock up completely. Also, you need to periodically clear the log panel. It works ideally when you're not generating so many logs that it can't keep up. Or just use VS Code or another tool of your choice.

Answer (score 2):

While I think IE7 is supported for the "main" browser experience with Salesforce, I do not think Developer Console officially supports it.  The latest version of Chrome is supported.

Your IT department should be informed that you are running into scenarios where IE7 is not supported for basic developer scenarios.  Using a browser that was designed for 2006 in 2014 is probably going to run into some issues.

Comment: Also, see [Supported Browsers](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=getstart_browser_overview.htm&language=en), which says: "Internet Explorer 7 and 8 aren’t supported for the Developer Console"